# How to load NPAPI on QT 5.3 embedded system?

Tags: npapi, qtplugin

I have NPAPI plugin file - libxxxplugin.so.
Is it possible to load this plugin file onto QT embedded linux system?
I made a browser using QWebView, and put it in QTWEBKIT_PLUGIN_PATH directory as described in PluginDatabase.cpp. 
But, "navigator.mimeTypes" returns nothing.

Any suggestion would be help.

Thanks.